# Firestore bundles appears to be more expensive than regular queries?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

### A case study for cost difference between fetching data from:

> 1. **Firestore Queries**
> 2. **Firestore Bundles**

But what are Firestore Bundles? https://firebase.blog/posts/2021/04/firestore-supports-data-bundles/

Setup:
I have 1282 documents in a collection & each document has 6 properties:

1. subject_name : *string*
2. subject_code : *string*
3. date : *Timestamp*
4. last_updated : *Timestamp*
5. id : *string*
6. course_count : *number*

---

**1. Firestore Queries**

Source:
https://cloud.google.com/firestore/pricing

To calculate Firestore queries cost, I will be using the Frankfurt (Europe-west3) as reference. Network egress (outbound data transfer) cost is neglected.

- 0.039$ per *100,000 reads*

Cost of 1282 document reads per person:

- 0.039 * 1282/100,000 = **5e-4$** or **0.0005$**

---

**2. Firestore Bundles**

Source: https://firebase.google.com/pricing

To calculate bundle cost, I will neglect the 1282 initial document fetches done by cloud functions to compose a buffer which is the bundle. This is because this will only be done once, then bundle could be fetched at no additional query read costs. Each person will get the data from firebase cloud storage so document reads are not applied but network bandwidth from fetching the bundle.txt file is considered instead.

- 0.12$ / *GB downloaded*
- 1282 documents bundle is 1 MB.

Cost of 1 MB bundle download per person:

- 0.12 * 1e-3 = **1.2e-4** or **0.00012$**

---

**Conclusion**

Creating data bundles seems to be 4 times cheaper than fetching from queries.

- (1.2 / 5) * 100 = 24%

Important to note that:

> 1. In my use case, my document size is very small, there are no long texts (books, threads). This would increase the size of the bundle, increasing the downloading cost, but keep the fetching from queries cost the same. I suggest not using bundles with large documents. **It would be more expensive.**

> 2. Size of numbers in a Firestore document is always 8 bytes. But not in a bundle since it is a .txt file. A huge number will take up more space. Source: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/storage-size

> 3. Complexity: You need to implement a firebase cloud function to run in a schedule or every time the collection is updated to make a new bundle. The changes in the collection cannot be updated in the previous bundle, a new one with a new query from scratch is needed.

> 4. Security: With bundles, you could lock down a collection with Firestore rules and data be exclusively accessed through bundles which your function composes. This is also dynamic as you can change what the function queries without rolling new update to client.

> 5. Cost: As seen above. However, you could save more if you are using a server costing more than Frankfurt `Europe 3 (eur3)` at 0.06$ per 100k reads

> 6. Versatility: One bundle can be many different queries together, a document from here, 20 documents from that collection, 50 from this. When downloaded to client, Firebase SDK automatically distributed these documents to where they belong. You just fetch them using a query from the device's cache.

> 7. Hybrid use case: The way I implemented them is running a scheduled cloud function every 24 hours to make a bundle in a collection, then every time a user refreshes, I query the documents from firestore directly applying a filter where the `last_updated` property is greater than the greatest `last_updated` in the bundle.

> 8. Ideal use: From what I gathered, a large number of small documents are where bundles reduce the most amount of cost.

Answer (score 0):

Your comparison is only on bandwidth used.

For the majority of the projects that I see, the main component of the cost they incur for Firestore comes from document reads - not from bandwidth. When you use a bundle to distribute documents, you only read them from Firestore once per time you create a bundle - instead of reading the same documents over and over for every user.

So you should add the cost of document reads to your calculation for a fairer comparison.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Can you please clarify because I did add the cost of read in the first couple lines.

Comment: Your cost example doesn't include the document read cost of the individual users, which is the majority of the cost. If you think you *do* include that cost, please edit your question to show a more exact calculation (maybe in the form of an actual formula?)

Comment: Updated, would love to hear your thoughts about point 1 in the conclusion.